# Creating a list of existing aws_instance resources in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm currently trying to find a way to create a list of aws_instance type resources.

The ec2s are already configured. I imported them using Terraform, but I would like to have them as a single list, so I could perform actions like remote-exec on all of them at the same time.

I'm just not sure how can I declare a list type variable to include all existing aws_instance resources.

Any help would be much appreciated! Cheers.

EDIT:
As asked, I'm going to add some of the HCL:

As I stated, each instance is imported from an existing aws configuration.
This means I already have aws_instance blocks for each ec2.

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2_1" {
      *truncated*
}
```

I was wondering if there was a way to take these resources, and append them into a list.

I would like to create this list in order to perform actions on all instances at once, using the Provisioner remote-exec.

I tried creating a variable, but I'm afraid it doesn't function that way:

```
variable "ec2_list" {
        type = list
        default = [aws_instance.ec2_1, aws_instance.ec2_2,...]
}
```

But variables from main.tf cannot be used for variables.

I'm just curious if you can make a general resource to create a list under.
If you know anything, please let me know.

Comment: Is this as a one off thing? Terraform might not be the tool you want for this kind of thing as it's primarily about defining the lifecycle of a resource. You might be better off with using Ansible (which can use dynamic inventories) or something like ClusterSSH. It would help if you expanded your question to explain your use case.

Comment: You should post relevent part (code) of what you have tried so far.

Comment: I've added additional information, if you can review it, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You could use the [`aws_instances` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/3.3.0/docs/data-sources/instances) to get a list of instances matching some criteria (or all instances) but if you're wanting to run ad-hoc actions against instances I'll repeat that Terraform is not a good tool for that.

Comment: You could create a custom output from exported attributes to aggregate a list of these instances. How to specifically do it in your case would require more specific configs for your instance resources in your question.